# Can't get uploader.swf in Magento 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

In the tutorial for add image to product
[image]

But I cant see two buttons browser file and upload file in my instance
[image]

In DevTools received these messages [image]

Someone please help me how to fix it.

Comment: your webserver does not allow access to that file. please look into the error log of your webserver, it should have more information. then add that info to your question. otherwise this is hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

Access Denied/Forbidden (403) indicates that access to this file has been purposefully denied on the web server.

Either access is:

1. being blocked in a .htaccess file rule for either Flash files (.swf) or those specific Magento downloader files
2. access to vulnerable .swf files is being blocked by a mod_security rule
3. since the pre 1.9.2.x Magento downloader files have known issues, is being blocked by a specific Magento rule in a Web Application Firewall (WAF).
4. a Magento aware hosting provider has whitelisted access to the Magento downloader .swf files and your IP address needs to be added to the access list

Check with your hosting provider to see if they're running mod_security or a Web Application Firewall that might be generating the (403) Access Denied/Forbidden error.

Answer (score 0):

Default Magento provides three swf files in folder

```
skin\adminhtml\default\default\media\uploader.swf
skin\adminhtml\default\default\media\uploaderSingle.swf
skin\adminhtml\default\default\media\flex.swf
```

Check in your setup these files exist or not. If not take it from any default Magento setup.